# Change Data Capture on Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, change-data-capture

I need to migrate an existing CDC system based on Oracle to Hadoop. Anybody implemented CDC on Hadoop?  Please share the approaches of CDC on Hadoop. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please elaborate your use case a little more, what factors are driving this migration ? Does you use case have the [4 v's](http://www.ibmbigdatahub.com/infographic/four-vs-big-data)?